# Read file extension from XML attribute C#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

How can I read a file extension from an XML attribute and show it in datagridview ?

Here is my XML. For example I want in datagridview to be displayed only the .exe extension.

```
<dir ParentFolder="e:\">
  <file FileName="SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" />
  <file FileName="SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU (2).exe" />
  <file FileName="wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64b.exe" />
</dir>
```

I loaded the xml file and i can only display the SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe in DataGridViewTextBoxColumn for example, but i only need .exe to be displayed.Here is the code

```
      XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("directory.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());

      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      //Read xml to dataset
      ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["dir"]; 
      dataGridView1.DataMember  = "dir_file";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string yourPath = "SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe";
Path.GetExtension(yourPath); // returns '.exe'
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(yourPath); // returns 'SQLEXPR_x64_ENU'
Path.GetFileName(yourPath); // returns 'SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe'
```

You need to 'manually' format the cell value and call the GetExtension method.
Use the [CellFormatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

**Update 1:**

Sample code to format the cells.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "COLUMNNAME")
    {
        e.Value = Path.GetExtension(e.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

To avoid exceptions you can add a null check:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "COLUMNNAME") && (e.Value != null))
    {           
         e.Value = Path.GetExtension(e.Value.ToString());            
    }
}
```

Comment: Update 1 added with sample code to format the cells.

Comment: now its showing me An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  at this line  - e.Value = Path.GetExtension(e.Value.ToString());

Comment: Add an extra check around that line: **if(e.Value != null)** { e.Value = Path.GetExtension(e.Value.ToString());}

Comment: I did it. I put the following line of code .....................String stringValue = e.Value as string;
                if (stringValue == null) return;
                e.Value = Path.GetExtension(stringValue.ToString());

Comment: Thank you Odrai for help. You are the best.

Comment: I'm glad I could help and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

System.IO.Path has a property GetExtension() which will provide ".exe" in your case.

```
String pExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I need to get that "SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" from XML attribute and dont know how to do that and tu put it in DataGridViewTextBoxColumn . Any suggestion?